# How to re-save a dictionary key with multiple values in python?

Tags: python, django, django-models, sqlite

```
{
 "캡틴마블": ["20018348", "81533"], 
 "이스케이프룸": ["20018925", "81654"], 
 "돈": ["20018920", "81651"], 
 "라스트미션": ["20018934", "81658"], 
 "우상": ["20018907", "81650"],
}
```

I have fetched movie data and saved the data as shown above (as a dictionary).
I want to save them to my Django project, but the code below is not working for me.

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    movie_data_dict = data #like above format Json file
    for t, m in movie_data_dict.items():
         MovieData(title=t, movie_cd=m[0], movie_idx=m[1]).save()

class MovieData(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    movie_cd = models.IntegerField
    movie_idx = models.IntegerField
```

The error being thrown is:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: table parsed_data_movie_data has no column movie_idx
...
...
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table parsed_data_movie_data has no column movie_idx
```

[image: Full error trace]

Another Error after makemigrations

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "NameParser.py", line 48, in <module>
    MovieData(title=t, movie_cd=m[0], movie_idx=m[1] ).save()
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 485, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % kwarg)
TypeError: 'movie_cd' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Comment: There is a typo in your code. The third line should be `items()` instead of `itmes()`. Is this your issue? What output are you getting and what output are you expecting?

Comment: I edit them. I want to save 2nd value to movie_idx. But That's items format can't save more than 2

Comment: What do you mean you can't save more than 2? Are you currently receiving an error or are you just not getting your desired output?

Comment: Thank you for fixing the English sentence neatly. Attached is a picture with an error.

Comment: Have you ran `manage.py -makemigrations` and then `manage.py -migrate`?

Comment: It looks like your SQL table hasn't been created or the `movie_idx` column hasn't been added yet. Try @handras suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set up your fields incorrectly. Django is currently expecting your values from your list to be of type `IntegerField`. You need to either use `movie_cd=int(m[0]), movie_idx=int(m[1])` or change the expected field to a `CharField`.

Comment: `movie_cd=int(m[0])` same error, but `CharField` do well. Thank you! Grammer is very important.... I wasted 3 hours to this ㅠㅠ

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you added the attribute `movie_idx` to `MovieData` after you had already had an initialized database. When you do that you need to run `manage.py -makemigrations` and then `manage.py -migrate` (while the server is not running) to add the new attribute to your SQL table.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know I had to do that. But Another error comes up, Output2

Comment: @JackMoody @handras I think `movie_cd=m[0], movie_idx=m[1]` this index numbering is problem. Is there any fit method for me? I can't find